# General Relativity and Tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vectors

One-form $\tilde{p}=(1,1,1,1)$ is given along with its basis $\tilde{\lambda}^{\alpha}$. How can I find the $l_{\alpha}$

$\tilde{p}=l_{\alpha}\tilde{\lambda}^{\alpha}$

Do I have to lower the index of $\tilde{\lambda}^{\alpha}$ with the help of Minkowski Metric and then multiply it with $\tilde{p}$ to find projections of it onto all basis? Am I right? If not, kindly guide.

Answer (score 4):

You've already written them down.  $l_\alpha$ are the components of $\tilde p$ in the basis $\tilde \lambda^\alpha$, and are therefore all equal to $ 1$, based on the expression you wrote in your first line.